# Largest possible sphere is inscribed in a cube. What percentage is the volume of the sphere smaller than the volume of the cube?

Tags: trigonometry

Largest possible sphere is inscribed in a cube. What percentage is the volume of the sphere smaller than the volume of the cube?

I have already found out:

- volume of the cube is $X^3$
- volume of the sphere is $4/3\times \pi\times \text{radius}^3$
- area of cube is $6X^2$
- area of sphere is $4\times\pi\times \text{radius}^2$

Should I find the ratio next and then replace X?

Thank you for all your help.

Comment: Where are you stuck? 
The maximum diameter of an inscribed sphere would be equal to the side of the cube, as if it were any bigger, part of the sphere would lie outside of the cube. Take ratios of their volumes and you are on your way.

Answer (score 3):

If $s$ is the side length of the cube, we have that $V_{\text{cube}} = s^{3}.$ Notice that the largest possible sphere that can fit inside the cube is the inscribed sphere, which has radius $\frac{1}{2}s.$ Using the volume formula for a sphere, we find that $V_{\text{sphere}} = \frac{4}{3}\pi r^{3} = \frac{4}{3}\pi \frac{s^{3}}{8} = \frac{\pi}{6}s^{3}.$

To find the percentage, we must first find the ratio between the sphere and the cube. This is simply $\frac{\frac{\pi}{6}s^{3}}{s^{3}} = \frac{\pi}{6}.$ The sphere is $1 - \frac{\pi}{6} = \boxed{47.6\%}$ smaller than cube.

Answer (score 1):

It's a good question!

Our conditions:

1. A ball fits inside a box;
2. The ball is a perfect sphere and the box is a perfect cube;
3. The diameter of the ball is equal to the length of the box.

Question: If the length of the box is 1 unit, what is the ratio of the volume of the sphere with the volume of the box?

Well, first, we can know that the volume of the box is equal to 1 unit cubed:

$$V_{box}=1$$

We also can know that the radius of the sphere is equal to 1/2 units

$$r=1/2$$

And we know that the equation for a sphere is given as

$$V_{sphere}=\frac{4 \pi r^3}{3}$$

Substituting in our radius we have

$$V_{sphere}=\frac{4 \pi}{3*8} = \frac{\pi}{6}$$

And now taking the volume ratio of the ball to the box, we get:

$$\frac{V_{sphere}}{V_{box}}=\frac{\pi/6}{1}=\frac{\pi}{6}$$

Therefore the ratio of our sphere to our box is:

$$\frac{\pi}{6}$$

Answer (score 0):

to restate @k-jiang 's excellent answer just a little, if you write the volume formula in terms of *diameter* instead of radius:
$$
V_{sphere}
= \left(\frac{d}{2}\right)^3*\frac{4\pi}{3} \quad
= \frac{d^3}{8}*\frac{4\pi}{3} \quad
= \frac{d^3}{2}*\frac{\pi}{3} \quad
= d^3*\frac{\pi}{6}
$$

..then the relationship becomes very clear:

$$\begin{aligned}
V_{cube} &= d^3 \\
V_{sphere} &= d^3*\frac{\pi}{6}
\end{aligned}$$

$\frac{\pi}{6}$ is about $0.52$, so a sphere's volume is approximately $52\%$ of a cube's having the same diameter, which is about $48\%$ less.